# HM-10 battery uses too much energy on ibeacon mode

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, hm-10

I m using hm-10 to deploy ibeacon with CR2450 battery.

But in several configurations, CR2450 battery drains too fast.

I need AT+MODE2

And AT+ADTY0 commands for ota and battery level.

In AT+ADTY3 mode device cannot send battery level in advertising data.

Is it possible to work battery level data in AT+ADTY3 mode or AT+ADTY3 mode with low power consumption?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a firmware bug in the HM-10 that causes AT+BATC1 to draw excessive current when in sleep mode with AT+SLEEP or AT+PWRM0. It would not show at first, however usually after 3 hours, the bug arises and the devices starts to draw more current.

advertising @ 1284 ms with AT+BATC0 = 1.6 uA with radio peaks.
advertising @ 1284 ms with AT+BATC1 = 600 uA with radio peaks when the bug occurs.

I have not found a solution except turning off battery level reporting... It might be that the bug is solved in later firmware, I have not tested that.

Kind regards

Comment: Thank you so much. I ve tested version 540 and also the same situation happened. And huamao doesnt answer this question because they re selling ibeacons..